Tabular colums separator continuous line
How can I make the column separator a continuous line? As you can see from the output, the vertical line breaks at the horizontal lines
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}[ht]{cc|cc}
            \toprule
            $m$ & $\bar{\nu}$ ($\unit{cm^{-1}}$) & $m$ & $\bar{\nu}$ ($\unit{cm^{-1}}$) \\ \midrule
            1 & 2146.87 & -1 & 2139.15\\
            2 & 2150.48 & -2 & 2135.39\\
            3 & 2154.33 & -3 & 2131.44\\
            4 & 2157.95 & -4 & 2127.34\\
            5 & 2161.57 & -5 & 2123.48\\
            6 & 2165.43 & -6 & 2119.38\\
            7 & 2168.8 & -7 & 2115.29\\
            8 & 2172.42 & -8 & 2111.19\\
            9 & 2176.03 & -9 & 2107.09\\
            10 & 2179.41 & -10 & 2102.99\\
            11 & 2183.03 & -11 & 2098.89\\
            12 & 2186.4 & -12 & 2094.56\\
            13 & 2189.77 & -13 & 2090.46\\
            14 & 2193.15 & -14 & 2086.12\\
            15 & 2196.52 & -15 & 2081.78\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}



You are using booktabs to make the horizontal lines, that package has very clear rules on how to use vertical rules in tables, so don't use the vertical rules or use standard \hline (the first choice is usually better)

This is features of booktabs rules. They are not intend to use in table with vertical rule. If you will omit them, table will (to my opinion) looks nicer ...

Off-topic: (a) [ht] is not a meaningful option for tabular. Did you mean to affix [ht] to \begin{table}? (b) \unitcan function in both text and math mode. For columns 2 and 4, there's no need to switch to math mode to render the \unit instructions.

Considering comments below your question, your table should be written as follows:

In code for above table I use S of siunitx for define columns style:
\documentclass{article}
%usepackage{pgfplots}      % not used in this MWE
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}  % not used in this MWE
%\usepackage{amsmath}       % not used in this MWE
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ S[table-format=2]S[table-format=4.2] @{\qquad} S[table-format=-2] S[table-format=4.2]}
            \toprule
            {$m$} & {$\bar{\nu}$ (\unit{\centi\meter\per\second})} & {m} & {$\bar{\nu}$ (\unit{\centi\meter\per\second})} \\ 
            \midrule
            1  & 2146.87 & -1  & 2139.15\\
            2  & 2150.48 & -2  & 2135.39\\
            3  & 2154.33 & -3  & 2131.44\\
            4  & 2157.95 & -4  & 2127.34\\
            5  & 2161.57 & -5  & 2123.48\\
            6  & 2165.43 & -6  & 2119.38\\
            7  & 2168.8  & -7  & 2115.29\\
            8  & 2172.42 & -8  & 2111.19\\
            9  & 2176.03 & -9  & 2107.09\\
            10 & 2179.41 & -10 & 2102.99\\
            11 & 2183.03 & -11 & 2098.89\\
            12 & 2186.4  & -12 & 2094.56\\
            13 & 2189.77 & -13 & 2090.46\\
            14 & 2193.15 & -14 & 2086.12\\
            15 & 2196.52 & -15 & 2081.78\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}

